# In ubercart module, how can we change currency sign $ to Rs.?

Tags: drupal-6

In [ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module, how can we change currency sign $ to Rs.? I want to give product price in rs., but ubercart module takes $ by default.

Comment: Hi there. You've got a couple of replies over a year old, but you didn't reply to them. Please take the time to reply to people who help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual you should be able to set the currency format here:

> Administration » Store » Configuration » Store (admin/store/settings/store).

http://drupal.org/node/1311876

Answer (score 0):

You can set default currency and sign from :

(admin/store/settings/store/edit/format)